# Launching SharePoint Management Shell (PowerShell) From C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell

I am attempting to programmatically launch the SharePoint Management Shell from C# code and I am getting different behavior that when I select it from the Start Menu.  I have attempted to do this two different ways with the same result:

Attempt #1:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\PowerShell.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "-NoExit \"  & 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\CONFIG\\POWERSHELL\\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1' \"";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Attempt #2:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products\\SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.lnk";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Both of these methods launch a PowerShell window and display the following error message:

> File C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\CO NFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\SharePoint.ps1 cannot be
>   loaded because the execut ion of scripts is disabled on this system.
>   Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details. At line:1 char:3
>   +  & <<<<  ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensio ns\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1 '
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

When I launch it from the Start Menu, it works just fine.  Any ideas on why this behaves differently?  In Attempt #1 I am running the same executable and arguments as the Link.  In Attempt #2 I am trying to run the link itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by x86 and x64 PowerShell each requiring ExecutionPolicy to be set to something other than `Restricted` in order to run scripts.  Perhaps your PowerShell console is x64 and your C# program is running as x86 or vice-versa.  Either way, pass in an additional parameter to PowerShell `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` to skip past this particular problem.

Comment: Brilliant! The x86 vs x64 was the issue.  I added your flag and also set my application to compile to x64 (which was necessary anyway) and voila, it works.  I'll mark as answer in a few minutes when it lets me.  Thanks!